# Query on Date Fields using CAML

Tags: sharepoint, object, model, client, caml

I am trying to run a query against a sharepoint list (using the client object model), finding an item that matches on a date field.

My query is:
    
        
           
              
                 
                    2012-07-24T02:50:28
              
           
           1

I know that there is an item in the list where the EmDateSent field has the value 2012-07-24T02:50:28 and yet when I run this I get 0 rows back.

Having spent hours researching and experimenting I found that the date formatting I have used works - or so I thought. It seems that now it doesn't.

My code is below.

Can anybody suggest something else I can try?

```
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = String.Format(
    @"<View>
         <Query>
             <Where>
                <Eq>
                   <FieldRef Name='{0}'/>
                      <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='True'>{1}</Value>
                </Eq>
             </Where>
         </Query>
      </View>", EMAIL_FIELD_DATE_SENT, details.DateSent.HasValue ?   details.DateSent.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss") : "");


ListItemCollection listItems = upLoadList.GetItems(camlQuery);

_context.Load(listItems);
_context.ExecuteQuery();

if (listItems.Count > 0)  // At this point I expect listItems.Count to be 1, but it is   0
{
    ....
```

Comment: You got to perform this query using U2U program? To make sure there records with this filter?

Comment: Try the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` (without the 'T'). A date must be provided this way (see http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/symbols/%24SP%28%29.list.html#.add for the different formats to use in a CAML query)

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks correct, and there is not an issue with using the "T" in the time stamp.  However, from what I can find, most of the examples like yours use the [`SPQuery` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery.aspx) instead of the [`CamlQuery` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.camlquery.aspx).  I believe this is causing your issue.